# Hold reponsible for

Tags: grammar, subject-verb-agreement

Good day, pls. Help me if this is grammatically correct.

Interviewer: do you like your city mayor?(let's say a male)

> Someone: YES, BECAUSE HE HOLD RESPONSIBLE FOR WHAT HE SAY.

My question is about 'the answer' of the someone **if the subj-verb agreement is perfectly met.** coz 'HE-SAY' should be 'SAYS' right? Or 'HE HOLD or HE HOLDS?'

Another is, **if you can suggest way(s) to improve** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model response is in all kinds of grammatical trouble:

First, it's necessary to hold **someone/group/organisation** responsible.

You can't just: *hold responsible* because it needs an object. However you (who are someone) can be **held responsible** in the passive voice.

So either the city mayor holds other people responsible for what he says (which is unlikely in this context) or he *takes responsibility* himself.

**He** requires the singular **says** and not **say** - similarly **holds** and not **hold**.

So it's probable that the response should read:

> Yes, because he takes responsibility for what he says

However, it's more common to say in this context that:

> ...the mayor keeps his word....

or

> > ...the mayor does what he says he will do...

Other expressions are:

> to carry the can

meaning to take responsibility, and

> the buck stops here

meaning, this is the person who is responsible for the decision/s

Comment: 'I do whatever things I say I will do'-is this correct now? Thx for your detailed answer, got it.

Comment: @JohnArvin It's correct but not idiomatic. A native speaker would probably say either: *I do whatever I say I will do* or *I do what I say I will do*. More popular is *to put your money where you mouth is*.

Comment: I have learned a new idiom just now, excellent!(to put your money where your mouth is). I will use this whenever appropriate coz it's catchy hehe, HOWEVER, if a situation goes like this: interviewer: are you a reliable camaraderie? Me: Yes I am, also I am fiercely proud about this coz this is a positive trait, to put your money where your mouth is just second to none. Can I say that? That's my last question, hope you don't mind, coz I wanna make this as flexible and as accurate as I can. Thx

Comment: @JohnArvin I think it would depend on the interview.